# pChart input in array

Tags: php, android, pchart

I'm tryin to input into my array string obtained from retreiving data from file. But it reads only first value.
This is how i'm retreiving data set;

```
$file = explode("   ", file_get_contents("data/data-02"));
foreach ( $file as $content ) 
    {
        $result[] = array_filter(array_map("trim", explode("    ", $content)));
    }
//var_dump($result);
//echo $result[0][1];
    $time = '';
    for ($id = 1; $id < 20; $id+= 6)
    {
        $time .=  '"'.$result[0][$id].'"'.',';
    }
    $sugar_1 = '';
    for ($id = 2; $id <20; $id+=6)
    {
        $sugar_1 .= $result[0][$id].',';
    }
    $sugar_2 = '';
    for ($id = 5; $id <20; $id+=6)
    {
        $sugar_2 .= $result[0][$id].',';
    }
```

ex. echo sugar_1 is

> 58,60,62,48,58,60,62,48,58,62,48,58,60,62,48,58,60,62,48,58,60,62,48,58,60,62,48,58,60,62,48,58,60,

and now i'm trying to input this into

```
/* pChart library inclusions */ 
 include("pChart/class/pData.class.php"); 
 include("pChart/class/pDraw.class.php"); 
 include("pChart/class/pImage.class.php"); 

 /* Create and populate the pData object */ 
 $MyData = new pData();   
 $MyData->addPoints(array($sugar_1),"Probe 1"); 
 $MyData->addPoints(array($sugar_2),"Probe 2"); 
 $MyData->setSerieTicks("Probe 2",4); 
 $MyData->setAxisName(0,"Sugar level in blood"); 
 $MyData->addPoints(array($time),"Labels"); 
 $MyData->setSerieDescription("Labels","Hours"); 
 $MyData->setAbscissa("Labels");
```

but as I said, it's reading only first value, but for example if i'm gonna add smth there like

`$MyData->addPoints(array($sugar_1**,44,66**),"Probe 1");` then those added values working perfectly. I'm out of my types to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

solved.

```
header("Content-type:text/plain");
$file = fopen("data/data-02", "r");

$result = array();
$file = explode("   ", file_get_contents("data/data-02"));
foreach ( $file as $content ) 
    {
        $result[] = array_filter(array_map("trim", explode("    ", $content)));
    }
//var_dump($result);
//echo $result[0][1];
$time = array();
$k=0;
    for ($id = 1; $id < 31; $id+= 6)
    {
        $time[$k] =  '"'.$result[0][$id].'"'.',';
        $k++;
    }
    $sugar_1 = array();
    $k=0;
    for ($id = 2; $id <30; $id+=6)
    {
        $sugar_1[$k] = $result[0][$id].',';
        $k ++;
    }
    $sugar_2 = array();
    $k=0;
    for ($id = 5; $id <33; $id+=6)
    {
        $sugar_2[$k] = $result[0][$id].',';
        $k++;
    }

 /* pChart library inclusions */ 
 include("pChart/class/pData.class.php"); 
 include("pChart/class/pDraw.class.php"); 
 include("pChart/class/pImage.class.php"); 

 /* Create and populate the pData object */ 
 $MyData = new pData();   
 $MyData->addPoints($sugar_1,"Probe 1"); 
 $MyData->addPoints($sugar_2,"Probe 2"); 
 $MyData->setSerieTicks("Probe 2",4); 
 $MyData->setAxisName(0,"Sugar level in blood"); 
 $MyData->addPoints($time,"Labels"); 
 $MyData->setSerieDescription("Labels","Hours"); 
 $MyData->setAbscissa("Labels");
```